# button in updatepanel content template not firing

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Hi I have placed some code in an updatepanel on a web page and all works fine except for one button. Whats displayed in the updatepanel is just a number of items that a user has added to a shopping cart.

The buttons that work are btnPlus and btnMinus, they increase the quantity of an item in a shopping cart, and in their code behind this updates the quantities that are being stored in the database.

What's not working is the btnDelete - this is supposed to delete the item from the shopping cart.

When I click it nothing happens - but what's really strange(at moment) is that it does work after I click after I click btnPlus or btnMinus.

Any ideas?

```
                     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlSmallCheckout" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div class="basket">
                            <%Dim SmallCounter as integer = 0 %>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptSmallCheckout" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>

                                    <div class="item">

                                        <div class="image">
                                            <img src="/graphics/placeholders/sweets.jpg">
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="title">
                                            <%#Eval("PTitle")%> x<span class="amount" id="span_small_<%=SmallCounter%>"><%#Eval("Quantity") %></span><asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Quantity") %>' MaxLength="3" Style="display: block"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSmallNumKilos" runat="server" Style="display: block"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <asp:Literal ID="ltrSmallNumKilos" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Literal>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnMinus" CssClass="button minus" Text="-" runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>' OnClientClick="if (!update_qty('minus',this)) return false;" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnPlus" CssClass="button plus" Text="+" runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>' OnClientClick="if (!update_qty('plus',this)) return false;" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="x" CssClass="button remove" CommandName='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>'  OnClientClick="update_total(this);"  OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
                                        </div>

                                    </div>

                                    <%SmallCounter=SmallCounter+1 %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                            <!-- item -->
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any javascript error? Check using firebug / other tools

Comment: H @Rihith, I wasn't getting any error but there was the JS function that was being called by the (remove class click function) that must have been stopping the code behind from being fired - not sure why that was there(done by someone else) - but I've commented it out and it appears to be working now. Thanks. Put your comment in an answer and I'll tick it when I'm able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any javascript error? Check using firebug / other tools?

Errors might be interfering with the updatepanel postback event.

Answer (score 0):

not need to **return** the clientSidefunction otherwise the serverSide will not fire

```
OnClientClick="return update_total(this);"  OnClick="btnDelete_Click"
```

ensure "update_total()"  "returns true;" if you want to postback.